# I have a fixed table thead. If background-color: green, how to make th borders visible?

Tags: css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <style>
      
      table, th, td {
        border: 2px solid black;
        padding: 0.5em 1em;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      
      .theadfixed { 
        position: sticky; top: 0;
        color: black;
        background-color: green;
      }
      
      .theadfixed tr {
        border-color: black;
        border: 2px solid black;
      }
      
      .theadfixed th{ 
        text-align:center;
        border: 2px solid black;
      }
          
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <table>
    <thead class='theadfixed'>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" > Size </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> Length </th>
        <th> Width </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>17</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>18</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>21</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>22</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>24</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>26</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>27</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>28</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>31</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>32</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <style>
      
      table, th, td {
        border: 2px solid black;
        padding: 0.5em 1em;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      
      .theadfixed { 
        position: sticky; top: 0;
        color: black;
        background-color: green;
      }
      
      .theadfixed tr {
        border-color: black;
        border: 2px solid black;
      }
      
      .theadfixed th{ 
        text-align:center;
        border: 2px solid black;
      }
          
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <table>
    <thead class='theadfixed'>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" > Size </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> Length </th>
        <th> Width </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>17</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>18</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>21</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>22</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>24</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>26</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>27</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>28</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>31</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>32</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Above is the entire file.
I would like a vertical black line separating the "Length" and 'Width" column labels.
I think the background color covers up the border color.
I've tried different things such as:
border-color: black;
border: 2px solid black;
But nothing seems to work.
Can you help me make the th borders visible? Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the complete code sample that can repro your issue?

Comment: Good idea. I've added the entire file so you can see what I mean more clearly. Thanks

Comment: Did you see my answer? :)

Comment: Yes, please see comment below. Thanks

Comment: What about now?

Comment: Your fix is promising. Similar to Pixie Dust's. My original html is a simplified version of my actual code. I updated it so it's closer to what my <thead> actually looks like. Thanks

Comment: Please use updated html. My actual code has two rows in <thead>. Sorry for throwing a wrench in the works. Also how do i delete the duplicated html below "Run Code Snipped". Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <style>
         table,
         td,
         th {
         border-collapse: collapse;
         padding: 0.5em 1em;
         border: 2px solid black;
         }
         .theadfixed th {
         text-align: center;
         border: 2px solid black;
         background-color: green;
         position: sticky; 
         top: 0;
         }
         .theadfixed th::before {
         content: '';
         position: absolute;
         height: 1px;
         width: 100%;
         top: -1px;
         left: 0;
         background-color: black;
         }
         .theadfixed th::after {
         content: '';
         position: absolute;
         width: 100%;
         bottom: 0;
         left: 0;
         background-color: black;
         }
         .SolveStickProblem{
         top:35px!important;border:2px solid black;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <thead class='theadfixed'>
            <tr>
               <th colspan="2" > Size </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th  class="SolveStickProblem"> Length </th>
               <th class="SolveStickProblem"> Width </th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>654</td>
               <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>256</td>
               <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>78</td>
               <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>654</td>
               <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>654</td>
               <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>256</td>
               <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>78</td>
               <td>7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>654</td>
               <td>8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>654</td>
               <td>9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>256</td>
               <td>10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>78</td>
               <td>11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>654</td>
               <td>12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>654</td>
               <td>13</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>256</td>
               <td>14</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>78</td>
               <td>15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>654</td>
               <td>16</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>654</td>
               <td>17</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>256</td>
               <td>18</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>78</td>
               <td>19</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>654</td>
               <td>20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>654</td>
               <td>21</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>256</td>
               <td>22</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>78</td>
               <td>23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>654</td>
               <td>24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>654</td>
               <td>25</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>256</td>
               <td>26</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>78</td>
               <td>27</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>654</td>
               <td>28</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>654</td>
               <td>29</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>256</td>
               <td>30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>78</td>
               <td>31</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>654</td>
               <td>32</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Also here is [Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) of HTML Table

Comment: The table <thead> section should stop at the top of page when scrolling, so if table has a million rows I can still see what is the label for each column.

Comment: @RoRprog978 What about now?

Comment: Please use updated html. My actual code has two rows in <thead>. Sorry for throwing a wrench in the works.

Comment: @RoRprog978 I have updated my answer with the new HTML Documant and I fixed Scroll problem for better User Experience. I think it is now fine. :)

Comment: @RoRprog978 Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Specify border width....**

Try this:

```
.theadfixed th { 
    text-align:center;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
```

**Edit:**

Add this to your css:

```
  tbody td:nth-child(odd) {
    border-right: 4px solid black;
  }
  
  tbody td:nth-child(even) {
    border-left: 4px solid black;
  }
```

**Final file:**

please notice that I have used the snippets in stackoverflow, so you can run it right here and see the result. :)

```css
table, th, td {
        border: 2px solid black;
        padding: 0.5em 1em;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      
      .theadfixed { 
        position: sticky; top: 0;
        color: black;
        background-color: green;
      }
      
      .theadfixed tr {
        border-color: black;
        border: 2px solid black;
      }
      
      .theadfixed th{ 
        text-align:center;
        border: 2px solid black;
      }
      
      tbody td:nth-child(odd) {
        border-right: 4px solid black;
      }
      
      tbody td:nth-child(even) {
        border-left: 4px solid black;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <table>
    <thead class='theadfixed'>
      <tr>
        <th> Length </th>
        <th> Width </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>16</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had tried that but it doesn't work for me. I included the entire file so you can test your suggestions.

Comment: Please check now, if the problem has been solved :) If it is please upvote.....

Comment: I need a vertical line between Length and Width.

Answer (score 0):

Before going through the code you should know that `position:sticky;` does not work on `<theads>` neither `<tr>`.
So an effective and simple way would be to use `postition:sticky;` on the the `<th>` element.
Also, there is no point in setting border property multiple times to the same element as if it would magically fix your issue.

However on scrolling you see that the border around the `<th>` moves up. Hence to still mimic the border on the top and bottom, css psudeo elements have been added.

If you need further clarification i suggest you to check this post from css-tricks by chris coyier. https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tesst</title>

  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    table,
    td,
    th {
      padding: 0.5em 1em;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
    
    .theadfixed th {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      text-align: center;
      border: 2px solid black;
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .theadfixed th::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      height: 2px;
      width: 100%;
      top: -1px;
      left: 0;
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    .theadfixed th::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      height: 1px;
      width: 100%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <thead class='theadfixed'>
      <tr>
        <th> Length </th>
        <th> Width </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>256</td>
        <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've added the entire file. Please take a look to see what I mean. Thanks

Comment: I understand it now, as your question is more clear than before. I believe that you want to make your ```<thead>``` stick to the top when user scrolls down, right?

Comment: @RoRprog978 please check if the above solution worked for you. Cheers.

Comment: Also (not that it matters, neither breaks the code) in ```::after``` if you change the ```height``` to *2px* and ```bottom``` to *-1px*, i would say that the code will be more *precise*.

Comment: Your fix is promising. My original html is a simplified version of my actual code. I updated it so it's closer to what my <thead> actually looks like. Thanks

Comment: @RoRprog978 ok. If you think it helped in anyway, you could support me with an upvote.

Comment: Also, if you had given the complete code on the 2nd edit, i might have been able to give you the complete solution. In any case you have solved your problem, which is exactly what we all want.

Comment: I tried to upvote you, but I'm new to stackoverflow so I'm not able to do that it seems.

Comment: Oh! It's alright.
@RoRprog978 But aren't you a member for 2years? How come you only have 5rep?